# How Avraham could receive the Divine Presence?

Tags: tanach, eretz-yisrael, avot-patriarch-fathers, nevua-prophecy, parashat-lech-lecha

How Avraham was able to receive the Divine Presence if he was not in Eretz Israel and had no brit milah?

Comment: This question could be improved if you sourced the idea that one can not receive the Divine Presence when A) Not in Eretz Yisroel B) has no Bris Milah.

Comment: ...or at least gave some reasoning as to why you suspect that might be the case.

Comment: Very related source: *Kuzari* chapter 2, sections 12-14. Russian link is here: http://www.morashasyllabus.com/Russain/curriculum/Eretz_-_Mahshaevet.pdf

Comment: When did Abraham receive the Shechinah before his bris? The earliest I know is Gen 18:1.  Before that, it seemed like it was prophecy, not receiving the Shechinah.

Comment: Not sure... But I believe that Rambam states that to receive divine presence or nevua, the person needs to be in a high level of spirituality and knowledge...knowing that G´d had to say to Avraham to keep these mitzvot, I presume that he didnt had the nescessary knowledge and spirituality

Comment: G-d revealed himself to Noach.

Comment: @Menachem ...and Adam.

Comment: @Menachem ...and Bilaam.

Comment: And Yonah received it outside Nineveh.

Comment: @MonicaCellio but that was after receiving it in EY. I think that the Gemara uses that answer for Yechezkel also.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, so the question is asking about *first contact* only?  That wasn't clear to me.  (As noted in other comments, the question would be much improved if it supported its assumptions, too.)

Answer (score 1):

God is all capable. He also revealed himself to Yechezkel outside Israel and Bilaam who was a big rasha. I think it's just "normally" in israel in the "normal" spiritual system of prophecy. but just like God can perform miracles and override the normal physical system, so too He can do a miracle in the "normal" way of prophecy and grant someone prophecy even outside Israel

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the opinions (I believe Rashi holds like this, contrary to the Ramban, according to whom it is a nice question), the prophecy in the beginning of *parshas Lech Lecha* ("go for your sake ... to the land that I will show you") was not the first one experienced by Avraham. Rather, the first one was the Covenant Between the Parts, which did happen in the Land of Israel.